# open webpage in firefox

Tags: browser

i am not sure..is there any chance to open my webpage in firefox. for example i am browsing mywebsite using IE. when ever i click link of the page then automatically it will open in firefox. this option is not for all pages only for specified page.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If this were the case, ie6 would have gone out long ago. The best you can do here, would be to check which browser they are using ([get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) if you are using php) and refuse to show content to people using browsers other than firefox.

Instead you could redirect them to a page explaining why they need to be using firefox to access your websites services (I guess a link to the firefox download page would be nice too)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it's not possible from plain HTML to open a webpage in a different browser. You can, at most, open the page in a new window of the *same* browser.

However, what you ask is not completely impossible. You could write a browser plugin that handles links and runs the Firefox executable

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously hope this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for is not possible , but you could display a warning to your users that the page works best in the desired browser.